# Random value from multidimensional array

Tags: javascript, arrays

Via javascript, I am trying to display a random value from an array after cycling through select objects within the array.  I have this working except I only want the first part of the array to show not both values.  I have it working perfectly showing both values but I can't get it to just show the first item in the random array selected (Ex: Op1 not Op1Opt1b).  Here is my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

        var i, word, rnd, words, fadeSpeed, timer;

        words = [
            ['Opt1','Opt1b'], 
            ['Opt2','Opt2b'], 
            ['Opt3','Opt3b'], 
            ['Opt4','Opt4b'], 
            ['Opt5','Opt5b'], 
            ['Opt6','Opt6b'], 
            ['Opt7','Opt7b'], 
            ['Opt8','Opt8b'], 
            ['Opt9','Opt9b'], 
            ['Opt10','Opt10b'], 
            ['Opt11','Opt11b'], 
            ['Opt12','Opt12b'], 
            ['Opt13','Opt13b'], 
            ['Opt14','Opt14b'], 
            ['Opt15','Opt15b'], 
            ['Opt16','Opt16b'],
            ['Opt17','Opt17b'], 
            ['Opt18','Opt18b'], 
            ['Opt19','Opt19b'], 
            ['Opt20','Opt20b']
        ];

        timer = 100;

        for(i = 0 ; i < 8 ; i ++) {
            if(i===8) {
                word= words[rnd];
            }
            else {
                rnd= Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length);
                word= words[rnd];
                words.splice(rnd, 1);
            }
    
            (function(word) {
                $('h1').fadeOut(fadeSpeed, function() {
                    $(this).html(word);
                })
                .fadeOut('fast')
                .delay(timer)
                .fadeIn('fast');
            })(word);
        }

    });
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
h1 {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1></h1>
```

Comment: `$(this).html(word[0]);`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to change the html you are showing

```
$('h1').fadeOut(fadeSpeed, function() {
    $(this).html(word[0]);
})
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

        var i, word, rnd, words, fadeSpeed, timer;

        words = [
            ['Opt1','Opt1b'], 
            ['Opt2','Opt2b'], 
            ['Opt3','Opt3b'], 
            ['Opt4','Opt4b'], 
            ['Opt5','Opt5b'], 
            ['Opt6','Opt6b'], 
            ['Opt7','Opt7b'], 
            ['Opt8','Opt8b'], 
            ['Opt9','Opt9b'], 
            ['Opt10','Opt10b'], 
            ['Opt11','Opt11b'], 
            ['Opt12','Opt12b'], 
            ['Opt13','Opt13b'], 
            ['Opt14','Opt14b'], 
            ['Opt15','Opt15b'], 
            ['Opt16','Opt16b'],
            ['Opt17','Opt17b'], 
            ['Opt18','Opt18b'], 
            ['Opt19','Opt19b'], 
            ['Opt20','Opt20b']
        ];

        timer = 100;

        for(i = 0 ; i < 8 ; i ++) {
            if(i===8) {
                word= words[rnd];
            }
            else {
                rnd= Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length);
                word= words[rnd];
                words.splice(rnd, 1);
            }
    
            (function(word) {
                $('h1').fadeOut(fadeSpeed, function() {
                    $(this).html(word[0]);
                })
                .fadeOut('fast')
                .delay(timer)
                .fadeIn('fast');
            })(word);
        }

    });
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
h1 {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1></h1>
```